# array "not used in this scope". Why?

Tags: c++, c

I'm getting an error saying that "adjacencymatrix' was not used in this scope" right at the end of main (before the function makebond at the end) (the commented line 112 "BROKEN LINE"). Why? Sorry about this being simple. I'm compiling with g++ ($ g++ a.c -o f).

Heres the code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
#define count 500

double density;
double volume;
int N;
double beta = 0.1;

double R = 5;
double rob = 1;

int dimension = 2;

double eps=0.1; // Increase in density
double mindensity = 0; // Minimum density
double maxdensity = 8; // max.dens (scaled for the sake of ensuring int()

int makebond(double x);

int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    for (int rho=mindensity;rho<=(maxdensity/eps);density++){

        N = floor(density*volume);

        double nodepositions[N][dimension];

        // Place nodes in volume (square side L, circle volume *R and obstacle *rob)
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            int L = 5;

            double distancefromorigin;

            double x = (L*(rand()/RAND_MAX))-(L/2);
            double y = (L*(rand()/RAND_MAX))-(L/2);

            distancefromorigin = sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));

                if(distancefromorigin<R){
                    if(distancefromorigin>rob){
                        nodepositions[i][0] = x;
                        nodepositions[i][1] = y;
                    }
                }
        }

        double adjacencymatrix [N][N];

        double itzhak; //distance of node 1 from the centre
        double isaac; //distance of node 2 from the centre
        double vivaldi; //distance between node 1 and node 2
        double phi; // a function of the above 3 doubles (see later usage)
        double rubicon; // maximum distance nodes within the icecream can be apart before becoming visually indepdendent
        double maxtheta; // "in the icecream" means theta < maxtheta
        double theta; // angular displacement of inner point from the line bisecting the icecream

        // Create adjacency matrix (note alternative implementation using incidence lists)

        for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<N;j++){

                double x0 = nodepositions[i][0];
                double y0 = nodepositions[i][1];
                double x1 = nodepositions[j][0];
                double y1 = nodepositions[j][1];

                itzhak = sqrt(sqr(x0) + sqr(y0));
                isaac = sqrt(sqr(x1) + sqr(y1));
                vivaldi = sqrt(sqr(x0-x1) + sqr(y0-y1));
                phi = ((sqr(vivaldi)+sqr(itzhak)-sqr(isaac))/(2*vivaldi*itzhak));
                rubicon = ((itzhak*phi) - sqrt((sqr(rob)) - ((sqr(itzhak))*(1-sqr(phi)))));

                maxtheta = asin(rob/itzhak);
                theta = acos(phi);

                if (x0==x1 && y0==y1){
                    adjacencymatrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else{       
                    if (isaac<itzhak && theta<maxtheta) {           
                        if (vivaldi>rubicon){   
                            adjacencymatrix[i][j] = 0;}
                        else {
                            adjacencymatrix[i][j] = makebond(vivaldi);}             
                    }

                else{adjacencymatrix[i][j] = makebond(vivaldi);}
                }

            }
        }

    }

    FILE *datafc1;
    datafc1 = fopen("matrix.dat", "w");

    for (int ii = 0; ii<N; ii++){
        for (int jj = 0; jj<N; jj++){       

            int aaa;
            aaa = adjacencymatrix[ii][jj];///////////////*******BROKEN LINE******
            fprintf(datafc1,"%i", aaa);

        }
    }

    fclose(datafc1);

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////
////////////////
///////  --End Main--
////////////////
////////////////////////////

int makebond(double x){

    // This function takes in the euc. dist. between two nodes and draws a link with prob. H(r)

    double randomnumber = (rand()/RAND_MAX); // Random number between 0 and 1
    double hr = exp(-beta*sqr(x));// ***Connection function***

    int a = 1; // Number to be put into adjacency matrix

    if (randomnumber > hr){
        a = 0;
    }

    return a; //Returns 0 or 1 depending on prob. dist.
}
```

Comment: [Avoid using `rand`.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 2):

`adjacencymatrix` is declared in your first `for` loop, so it's out of scope before the last spot you're using it, in the print-out loop at the bottom.

In addition, you have a useless `using namespace std;` line.  Your code doesn't include any headers that contain `std` namespace symbols.

Comment: how can I refer to it outside the loop?

Comment: You can't.  You need to declare it outside the loop or move your printing loop to the inside of that main loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in line 57:

```
    double adjacencymatrix [N][N];
```

is inside a for loop, outside that loop, `adjacencymatrix` is undefined.

Comment: how do I use it outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You matrix is defined in the for loop on line 11. Therefore it is out of scope on line 112.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *datafc1;
datafc1 = fopen("matrix.dat", "w");

for (int ii = 0; ii<N; ii++){
    for (int jj = 0; jj<N; jj++){

        int aaa;
        //error adjacencymatrix is declared in your first for loop
        aaa = adjacencymatrix[ii][jj];///////////////*******BROKEN LINE******
        fprintf(datafc1,"%i", aaa);

    }
}
```